# Mirror a website with httrack while executing javascript

Tags: javascript, http, download, youtube, httrack

I want do save a mirror of www.youtube.com/tv. I obviously do not want to save the videos. I want the code running the website in a local copy, everything else can stay remote. The code I want is mainly contained in 2 files: live.js and app-prod.js.

I tried using httrack. I have issue parsing the javascript to load anything past the first file: live.js. The %P parameter does not help.

```
httrack www.youtube.com/tv +* -r6 --mirror -%P -j
```

It doesn't go further than live.js because some javascript needs to be executed to load the next file.

I know I can do this manually with any browser. I want to automate the process.

Is httrack able to do this by itself?
If yes, how?

Comment: doubt you'll have much success due to access to ajax data

Comment: You were right. I ditched httrack and used python with http://docs.webscraping.com/ to navigate the website instead.